# How take a best key in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table like that :

```
$lol[24] = '2';
$lol[36] = '3';
$lol[48] = '4';
$lol[60] = '5';
```

I have a value '27', i need to say : '27, value before is 24, so my value is 2'

What is the best method for that ?

Comment: There's no built in function to do this. You'll need to write a function that checks each key and compares it to your number.

Comment: try this `code $lol[24] = '2';
$lol[36] = '3';
$lol[48] = '4';
$lol[60] = '5';

$value=40;
$val=0;
$c=0;
foreach($lol as $keys=>$vals){
   if($keys <= $value){
     $val=$vals;  
   }
}

echo $val`;